# javascript onclick function null

Tags: javascript, image, function, onclick

I have the following js function :

```
function Modification_Article()
{
     var photo = document.getElementById("photo_javascript");
     photo.innerHTML = "";
     document.getElementById("photo_delete_javascript").innerHTML = "";

     var loop = 0;
     for(loop = 0; loop < arguments.length; loop++)
     {
        if(loop < 3)
        {
            document.getElementById('Modification_Article_Id').value = arguments[loop];
            document.getElementById("Modification_Article_Titre").value = decodeURIComponent(arguments[loop + 1]);
            document.getElementById("Modification_Article_Text").value = decodeURIComponent(arguments[loop + 2]);
            loop += 2;
        }
        else
        {
            var image_to_delete = document.createElement('img');
            var path = arguments[loop + 1];

            var begin = path.substr(0, 32);
            var end = path.substr(32);

            var id = arguments[loop];
            console.log(id);

            image_to_delete.id = "image_" + id;
            image_to_delete.src = "images/Articles/" + begin + "_100x100" + end;

            image_to_delete.onclick = function(){ console.log(id); };

            photo.appendChild(image_to_delete);  
            loop += 1;
            image_to_delete = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The fact is when i print "id" the first time it's display "10" and "11" (according to photo's id), but the second time in the onclick function, only "null" is display. I really don't understand why ...

Comment: Can you please reproduce your problem in a fiddle (http://www.jsfiddle.com) so that it is easy for us to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with the use of `id` in the onclick function: In every IMG element created you are referencing THE SAME variable.

I think you expect, that when the `id` is referenced inside of the onclick function it is somehow copied and remembered by the function. This is not the case, it references the same variable and the value of this variable is the same as in the last iteration.

To fix this you might use something like this:

```
(function(id){
    image_to_delete.onclick = function(){ console.log(id); };
})(id);
```

In above code a copy of the id variable is made by passing it as a wrapping function parameter.

Comment: Amazing ! I knew it was something like that, but i don't know javascript enough to fix it. Thank you a lot.